# Center of percussion and sweet spot

Tags: classical-mechanics

I understood, when a ball is made to strike at the "center of percussion" of a baseball bat, the batter will not experience a perpendicular reaction force.

Could I regard the center of percussion as the "sweet spot"?

I read [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Center_of_percussion) that the two points may not be same.

I cannot understand the reason why the two points are different.

Could anyone explain?

Comment: Have a read of http://www.acs.psu.edu/drussell/bats/cop.html

Comment: nice reference~

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The wikipedia article (as well as the article linked by Farcher) says that the 'sweet spot' is subjective, a point at which it 'feels best' for the batter to hit the ball.  So this may depend on the batsman, the bat, and the force with which the ball is hit.

The Centre of Percussion is an objective point, measured relative to the pivot point, which is usually assumed to be where the batter grips the bat, about 6 in from the end.  However, studies have shown that at the moment the ball is struck the bat is pivoting about a point which is usually about 2.5 inches above the end of the bat and 2.5 inches off axis.  The true CoP should be measured from that point.

Other research indicates that the 'sweet spot' lies between the nodes of the lowest 2 vibrations of the bat. This minimises discomfort to the hands caused by vibrations excited by the impact.

Neither the CoP nor the 'sweet spot' maximises the velocity which the ball gains from the impact.

http://www.acs.psu.edu/drussell/bats/cop.html

Comment: It makes sense sweet spot might be located near nodes of vibration mode.

Comment: Can be, but its more dependant on the moments of inertia, rather than the elastic properties that affect the vibration modes (which are often measured in the wrong axis anyway)