# where is the best bounce on a racquet?

Tags: collision, elasticity

I am dropping a ball on a racquet, measuring bounce height against position. And the results are a bit all over the place. I found 3 places on the racquet that make the ball bounce higher. I read through lots of article online explaining the different points on the racquet, and still did not really get it. Can someone please explain the difference between node, COP, and COR on the racquet please. Thank you so much.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Center of percussion and sweet spot](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/266478)

Comment: @sammygerbil since the racquet is elastic the best bounce isn't necessarily at the center of percussion.